# c - How to handle strict aliasing warning

Tags: c, strict-aliasing, type-punning

Which is the easiest way to get rid of strict aliasing warning?

The code is:

```
uint8_t msg[3];
int retval;

msg[0] = (uint8_t) INT_READ_EVENT;
*((uint16_t *) &msg[1]) = bytesToRead;

retval = write(intPipe[1], msg, sizeof(msg));
```

bytesToRead is passed as an uint16_t value.

On the other end, there a read which receives a single byte to recognize event type (INT_READ_EVENT in this case) before remaining data is processed.

Is there any quick, simple way to get rid of the warning:

```
warning: dereferencing type-punned pointer will break strict-aliasing rules [-Wstrict-aliasing]
    *((uint16_t *) &msg[1]) = bytesToRead;
    ^
```

?

Comment: What about endianess? Are you sure you don't want portable code? Consider using bit shifts.

Comment: @Lundin Correct me if I'm wrong, but shall I really care about endianess? I just want to send it as uint16_t and receive later also as uint16_t value. Does it matter how the value is stored internally?

Comment: Sender computer will have endianess, the actual protocol will have endianess and the receiver will have endianess. If one of the three uses different endianess, you will have to care.

Comment: @Lundin Ok, I see.

Answer (score 3):

Like this, since it forces you do decide on the endianness that the 16-bit value should be represented as:

```
// Little-endian.
msg[1] = bytesToRead & 0xff;
msg[2] = (bytesToRead >> 8) & 0xff;
```

For big-endian, reverse the order of the right-hand sides.

Answer (score 3):

It sounds like you are decoding some sort of protocol, so one way is to declare a struct corresponding to the protocol data:

```
typedef struct
{
  uint8_t  something;
  uint16_t bytes_to_read;
} prot_data_t;
```

Then for convenience, and to dodge aliasing problems, you can put this in a union:

```
typedef union
{
  prot_data_t named_data;
  uint8_t     raw_data [sizeof(prot_data_t)];
} protocol_t;
```

Now you can transmit/receive data byte by byte through `raw_data` but access the different values through `named_data`.

---

Some things to consider:

Keep in mind that this code, as well as any solution not using bit shifts, will be endianess-dependent.

Code like this could be vulnerable to alignment and struct/union padding issues. For maximum portability, structs/unions aren't really recommended, unless you combine them with some serialization/deserialization routines.

Comment: ...and I was also DV now. Lol...?

Comment: Really nice that you mentioned `struct` padding. GCC does allow to eliminate it (unsure how this works on CPUs that can only address aligned memory locations) using some compiler-specific syntax, but that ties you to GCC, obviously.

Answer (score 2):

That warning is there for a reason.  If `msg` starts on a 16-bit boundary, then `msg[1]` does not.  So if you try to write a 16-bit value starting at the address of that field, you may trigger a trap for an invalid write to memory and cause a crash.

You should instead write the bytes one at a time.  Assuming you want the bytes in big-endian format (also called network byte order), you would do so as follows:

```
msg[1] = (uint8_t)(bytesToRead >> 8);
msg[2] = (uint8_t)(bytesToRead);
```

Comment: Could you please elaborate on the nature of this "invalid write" conditions?

Comment: @amn  See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19352232/unaligned-memory-access for more details.

Answer (score 1):

You can define a struct to do so, instead of use a char buffer.

```
struct message
{
    uint8_t code;
    uint16_t payload;
};

struct message msg;

msg.code = INT_READ_EVENT;
msg.value = bytesToRead;
```

Alignment and endianness must be taken into consideration on multiplatform/portable code.

If also want to access data of struct in raw mode you can:

```
union message_with_raw
{
    struct message msg;
    uint8_t rawdata[sizeof(struct message)];
}
```

Comment: I'm the fastest gun in the west! (we posted nearly identical answers :) )

Comment: @Lundin Well. I won for the first part, you the union one :) +1